# How to go to first or last (or the nth) occurrence from list of matched strings in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

To search of a particular string I am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.
After the list of lines with the string is found using <kbd>F3</kbd> I am moving to the next occurrence and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to go to the previous occurrence.

What is the keybinding to move to last occurrence and first occurrence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update for vscode v1.75:

There is a new command for going to any `nth` match of a Find:

```
Go to Match...
editor.action.goToMatchFindAction
```

It is not bound to any keybinding, but could be.  When you trigger this command it will open an input box asking which find match you want to go to - by number.  And it will indicate how many there are.

So it is a quick way of going to whichever match you want to jump to.

---

It doesn't look there is a built-in keybinding to go to the first/last find match.  But it is easy to make a macro that will do it.

After some recent changes to the `multi-command` (link below) extension, this is now quite easy to do (in `keybindings.json`):

```
  {
    "key": "alt+m",                     // whatever keybindings you wish
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "sequence": [
        "cursorTop",
        "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction"
      ]
    },
    // "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+m",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "sequence": [
        "cursorBottom",
        "editor.action.previousMatchFindAction"
      ]
    },
    // "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
```

You no longer need anything in the `settings.json` file.  The above keybindings are enough.

---

Previous answer:

Using some macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), put this into your settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

 {
   "command": "multiCommand.gotoFirstFindMatch",
   "sequence": [
     "cursorTop",
     "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction",
   ]
 },
 {
   "command": "multiCommand.gotoLastFindMatch",
   "sequence": [
     "cursorBottom",
     "editor.action.previousMatchFindAction",
   ]
 }
]
```

These are just based on the fact that if you first go to the top of the file and then go to the `next` find match, it will be the first one.  And likewise to go to the last find match:  first go to the end of the file and then seek the `previous` find match.

You will need your own keybindings to trigger these commands.  In keybindings.json:

```
 {
    "key": "alt+m",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { "command": "multiCommand.gotoFirstFindMatch" }
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+m",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { "command": "multiCommand.gotoLastFindMatch" }
  },
```

Here I used `m` for `match` and because these bindings likely do not conflict with any other keybindings you have.  But pick whichever key combinations you want.

[Keybindings updated for multi-command 1.40]

Comment: I am using linux machine. how to open Keybindings.json .

Comment: With Keyboard Shortcuts open (Gear Icon/Keyboard Shortcuts), click the first button on the far right (just to the left of the `split editor` button.  Or command palette and search for 
 `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` or bind this command: `workbench.action.openGlobalKeybindingsFile` to something.

Comment: Changing the "when" condition to "findWidgetVisible" will limit this to the necessary scope and make it work when the cursor is in the find window.